# Diagonalization of matrices of the form BAB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

If $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric matrices, the matrix $BAB$ is also a real symmetric matrix. My question is : knowing the orthogonal diagonalization of $A$ and $B$, can we obtain the orthonormal diagonalization of $BAB$ ?

Starting from $A = UDU^{\top}$ and $B = VD'V^{\top}$ with $U,V$ real orthogonal matrices and $D,D'$ diagonal matrices, we get :

$$ BAB = VD'V^{\top}UDU^{\top}VD'V^{\top} $$

which I do not find very helpful. My intuition is that the answer to the question is no. It is not even clear what the eigenvalues of $BAB$ would be in terms of $A$ and $B$. Can an additional hypothesis, such as "$B$ is positive definite" make the problem easier?

Comment: did you already do a concrete example, say, in 2x2?

Comment: @janmarqz No I did not. If $A$ and $B$ are $2\times2$ matrices, the eigenvalues of $BAB$ will be the solutions of : 

$$ X^{2} - \mathrm{tr}(BAB)X + \det(A)\big( \det(B) \big)^{2} = 0 $$

It is quite likely that, for an arbitrary real symmetric matrix $B$, the solutions of this equation have nothing in common with the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.